# how to handle subquery which returns more than one row

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1242

This is the query that I have written to fetch all reviews of Author-1.
Author-1 has written 2 posts each having many reviews. I want all those reviews.

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM `package_reviews`
  WHERE `post_id` = (SELECT `post_id` 
                     FROM `wp_posts` 
                     WHERE `post_author`=1);
```

Getting the error message as #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use join here.

Something like this.

```
SELECT * FROM `package_reviews` r LEFT JOIN `wp_posts` p ON r.post_id= p.post_id WHERE p.post_author = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
SELECT * FROM `package_reviews`
  WHERE `post_id` IN 
   (SELECT `post_id` FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_author`=1);
```

if you want to return all reviews.

Comment: When I do this, it returns reviews of all post_id. Its not filtering by post_author=1

Comment: Is post_author a numeric type ? Otherwise I don't understand why it doesn't filter.

Comment: When you use IN it does not match post_id with post_id of wp_posts. You need to use = to match, or do it by using JOIN(as stated in the accepted answer of this question)

Comment: I think then that your wp_posts.post_id is not a unique value. The join solution is more efficient, but using IN is the response to the error message you received (and sometimes JOIN is not possible). Glad you found an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the subquery by using LIMIT

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM `package_reviews`
 WHERE `post_id` IN (SELECT `post_id` 
                    FROM `wp_posts` 
                    WHERE `post_author`=1
                    );
```

Comment: When I do this, it returns reviews of all post_id. Its not filtering by post_author=1

Answer (score 0):

change your code like this :
SELECT * 
  FROM `package_reviews`
  WHERE `post_id` = ANY (SELECT `post_id` 
                     FROM `wp_posts` 
                     WHERE `post_author`=1);
this link is very useful
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-errors.html